# IE9 "Always refresh from server"

Tags: internet-explorer, page-refresh

In IE9 is an option: "Always refresh from server". If that option is turn off my page don't reload data from server but always get he same values from cache. Do you have any ideas how to force browser to refresh data from server using webpage code?

Answer (score 0):

You must set in your html headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```